# whats wrong in this simple mysqli query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This simple query works on localhost perfectly, but not in my hosting:

```
if (!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO orders (userid,cid,tipou,cantidad,factura,producto,lote,notas,cprod,pbase,cenvio,fecha,status,cobro,ip)

VALUES ('".$sessid."','".$cid."','".$tipou."','".$cantidad."','".$factura."','".$producto."','".$numlot."','".$notas."','".$cprod."','".$pbase."','".$cenvio."','".$fecha."','".$status."','".$cobro."','".$ip."')")) {
    echo "Falló la Insersión de Datos: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
} else {echo"Datos Insertados";}
```

Comment: Use prepared statements with parameter binding. There could be a quoting issue coming from your variables. You also didn't provide anything from your error, so it makes it really hard to tell.

Comment: can you please give me an example?

Comment: The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) is a good place to start.

Comment: The query simply dont insert anything into the table, and also dont return any error.

Comment: Im working with php.net documentation, and that query works on localhost (my pc) but when I upload the file to my hosting, dont work.

Comment: Try echoing your query and running it directly in the database.